# Nginx timeout not working with Amazon Linux 2 with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using `Amazon Linux 2` with elastic-beanstalk. I have `.ebextensions/00.nginx.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01.nginx.timeout.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
      proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
      proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
      fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
container_commands:
  nginx_reload:
    command: "sudo systemctl restart nginx"
```

But it doesn't appear to create that file. If it matters, I have some `.platform/hooks/prebuild/` files as well. Not sure if it's either / or?

Comment: In Amazon linux 2 you need to place the config under `.platform/nginx/conf.d/web.conf`

Comment: Add as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: And do I keep the same format with `files` and `container_commands`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Amazon linux 2 you need to place the config under

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/web.conf
```

> The following example demonstrates an application source bundle with several extensibility features that Elastic Beanstalk **Amazon Linux 2 platforms support**:

```
~/my-app/
|-- web.jar
|-- Procfile
|-- readme.md
and container commands
`-- .platform/
    `-- nginx/                # Proxy configuration
        |-- nginx.conf
        `-- conf.d/
            `-- web.conf
```

[Amazon Linux 2 platforms-linux-extend](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

Comment: does the file need to be named `web.conf`? Or it can be any name under that folder? For example could i name the file `proxy.conf`?

Comment: @sem10 The Elastic Beanstalk nginx configuration includes `.conf` files in this folder automatically. so yes you can